# how to open Azure Blob url with index.html

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

i have an Angular web site built and hosted as a static website on in Azure Blob storage.

url looks like this.

```
https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/yyyy/index.html
```

when i navigate to the url it works fine. but then browser strips out "index.html" and if user refreshes the page url gets invalidated. is there a way to get make a url as such that it opens correctly with or without .html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but then browser strips out "index.html"

No, the browser does not change the URI at all. There is nothing in HTTP that says `index.html` is implicit in a URI.

Follow these instructions for setting up a static website in Azure Blob storage:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

Specifically:

- Use the `{accountName}.{misc}.web.core.windows.net` host-name (you can configure a custom hostname separately). **Do not use the blob's direct URIs (`{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`)**
- Your file blobs must be located in a container named `$web` (which will be mapped to your `.web.core.windows.net` root).
- To specify the default-document (index document), i.e. the name of the blob that will be served when a blob filename is not specified, use the `az` command-line or `Enable-AzStorageStaticWebsite` PowerShell to specify `--index-document index.html` or whatever your website needs (e.g. `Default.html`, `Index.htm`, etc).