# Azure Managed Grafana with custom URL

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-managed-grafana

I set up an Azure Managed Grafana instance in Azure. It generated a custom URL for me. Let's say it's:

https://grafana-fzaeb1evc4d7cyaf.eus.grafana.azure.com (this is not the actual URL).

I also have a domain: `domain.com`.

I created a CNAME DNS record for `dashboard.domain.com` that points to `grafana-fzaeb1evc4d7cyaf.eus.grafana.azure.com`

It worked, but I'm getting a 404 from nginx. I'm guessing there's a configuration setting somewhere in Azure or Grafana to tell it to respond to my `dashboard.domain.com` URL, but I can't find it in either system and some Googling has yielded nothing.

Any thoughts on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting custom domain names for Azure managed instances of Grafana is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1101743/custom-domain-for-azure-managed-grafana-instance) yet.

The best what you can do right now is to set redirect from short name to default one.

Comment: can you share how can we set redirect from short name to default one?

Comment: @koiralo, I'm no expert to say the best approach. As an example, you can have simple Function returning 301 to Grafana's default address. Or maybe [bucket with index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58044671) ([how to redirect from index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538))